# Pedido pegando apenas o último produto cadastrado

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou criando um sistema simples para efetuar reservas de pedidos, onde trago os produtos do banco de dados através de um while simples, porém se tento colocar colchetes nos meus names, exemplo `name=name[]` ele traz todos produtos ao clicar somente em um, e se tiro os colchetes ele adiciona somente o último produto, independente de qual produto eu clique.

Tela de Compras na qual o usuário / cliente seleciona o item desejado para reservar.

```
<?php
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, codigo, descricao, preco FROM produtos'); 
?>

<form method="POST" action="salvar_pedido.php" class="">  

        <div class="row">

            <?php while ($produtos = $stmt->fetchObject()){ ?>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">

                    <div class="container">

                        <img style="width:75%;" src="imagem.php?id=<?php echo $produtos->id ?>" />

                        <div class="caption">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $produtos->id ?>"> <br>
                                <input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $produtos->codigo ?>"> <br>
                                <strong>Descrição:</strong> <?php echo $produtos->descricao ?> <input type="hidden" name="descricao" value="<?php echo $produtos->descricao ?>">  <br>
                                <strong>Preço: </strong>  R$: <?php echo number_format($produtos->preco,2) ?> <input type="hidden" name="preco" value="<?php echo $produtos->preco ?>"> <br><br>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Adicionar ao Pedido" id="comprar" name="comprar">
                        </div>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>

                </div>

            <?php } ?>

        </div>

</form>
```

arquivo salvar_pedido.php

```
    <?php

        if (isset($_POST['comprar'])){

                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $pedido = $_POST['pedido'];
                $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
                $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
                $preco = $_POST['preco'];
                $status = $_POST['status'];

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM pedido  WHERE pedido = '$pedido'"; 
                $resulta = $conn->query($sql);
                $row = $resulta->fetch_assoc();

                $result = "INSERT INTO pedido (pedido, data_venda, codigo, descricao, preco_venda, status) VALUES ('$pedido', NOW(), '$codigo', '$descricao', '$preco', '$status')";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);   

                if($resultado){
                    echo "<script>redirectPedido()</script>";
                    echo "<script>alert('Pedido Realizado com Sucesso');</script>";
                }  else  {
                    echo "<script>redirectPedido()</script>";
                    echo "<script>alert('Erro ao Realizar Pedido');</script>";
                }

        }

    ?>
```

Sempre que clico no Submit adicionar ao pedido ele adiciona apenas o último produto independente de qual item eu selecione. Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Como o $stmt foi gerado?

Comment: esqueci @Sveen, acabei de adicioná-lo acima do meu FORM

Comment: Precisa de um form cara cada conjunto de inputs e submits ou colocar os `names` com colchetes para enviar tudo de uma vez como um array.

Comment: então o estranho é que no momento do envio ele faz corretamente porém só pega o último produto da tabela de produtos sempre, mas, na lógica não deveria ocorrer isto não é? Já que estou informando o id dentro do while, pensei que fosse pegar o id respectivo a cada produto

Comment: vc só tem um form, como todos os campos tem o mesmo `name` ele envia só o último. Para enviar todos de uma vez só e com um form deixe seus campos assim: `<input type="hidden" name="id[]"` dê uma `print_r($_POST);` para conferir como foram enviadas as informações.

Comment: obrigado, eu não tinha pensado no array para está página, vou fazer o teste e mando o resultado aqui @rray

Comment: @rray tentei de diversas formas, porém sem sucesso, desta forma com colchetes eu passo a pegar todos os registros dentro o while clicando em apenas um único produto

Comment: blz.... então quando clicar no submit vc quer apenas pegar o id do produto daquele submit isso?

Comment: Sim eu queria acumular os produtos em uma lista referente aquele usuario, de uma forma que ele clicasse no submit de Adicionar ao Pedido e, ele pegasse o produto correto para adicionar ao pedido é só depois o usuário iria para outra página visualizar o pedido com cada prpduto que ele adicionou dai bastaria ele informar a quantidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver este problema você deverá rever a lógica da criação do seu form.

Neste código ele faz um while imprimindo várias vezes campos com mesmo ID, o que faz com que o campo fique duplicado e no submit ele assuma sempre o valor do último item.

Solução **ATUALIZADA** com as informações mais recentes incluídas na pergunta:

Pelo que foi indicado será um botão SUBMIT para cada item a ser adicionado ao carrinho, portanto deve haver um form para cada item, como segue:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, codigo, descricao, preco FROM produtos'); 
?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php while ($produtos = $stmt->fetchObject()){ ?>
              <form method="POST" action="salvar_pedido.php" class="">  
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="container">
                        <img style="width:75%;" src="imagem.php?id=<?php echo $produtos->id ?>" />
                        <div class="caption">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $produtos->id ?>"> <br>
                                <input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $produtos->codigo ?>"> <br>
                                <strong>Descrição:</strong> <?php echo $produtos->descricao ?> <input type="hidden" name="descricao" value="<?php echo $produtos->descricao ?>">  <br>
                                <strong>Preço: </strong>  R$: <?php echo number_format($produtos->preco,2) ?> <input type="hidden" name="preco" value="<?php echo $produtos->preco ?>"> <br><br>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Adicionar ao Pedido" id="comprar" name="comprar">
                        </div>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

---

Resposta anterior considerando que seria um SUBMIT que enviaria todos os registros:

Você tem duas soluções: Criar um array de campos "semelhantes" como o @rray disse ou um ID para cada campo do formulário.

Para isso só falta parar um pouco e testar a lógica. Pense nos inputs como variáveis... se você coloca $codigo = 987, depois coloca $codigo = 99999, no final a variável só vai ter o valor 99999 e não os dois.

Comment: na verdade ele traz os campos cada um com seu id, se eu deixar um input type text no ID, ele traz corretamente porém quando seleciono só busca o ID do último isso que me é estranho

Comment: tentei de diversas formas, porém sem sucesso, desta forma com colchetes eu passo a pegar todos os registros dentro o while clicando em apenas um único produto

Comment: Veja exemplo de uso em HTML e no PHP para pegar todos os dados na resposta escolhida (primeira) dessa pergunta feita aqui no stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314567/how-to-get-form-input-array-into-php-array

Comment: Se for para usar IDs específicos ao criar o form (produtos já existentes, como parece ser o seu caso), coloque de forma explícita os nomes dos input com os IDs associados no array ou em um input hidden... veja qual a melhor opção para você.

Comment: Veja a nova resposta com base nas informações indicadas, talvez seja o que quer... qualquer coisa mande mensagem na inbox.

Comment: consegui, era exatamente isso, obrigado pela ajuda, eu estava vacilando a respeito do form, utilizando um só rs